# Can't see smart dimensions on sketches

Tags: cad, solidworks

I'm running SolidWorks 2019-2020 on a Windows 10 laptop with a screen resolution of 3840 x 2160. I can create parts and sketches just fine, but the numbers on smart dimensions are so small that I can't even see them. I haven't found a way to change a default setting to resolve this issue - I've only resolved it on single documents. Thoughts?

[image: smart dimension screen shot]

Comment: Did you check this: https://www.javelin-tech.com/blog/2019/08/solidworks-dpi-scaling-issue/

Comment: Good idea - I just followed those instructions though, and it didn't fix anything. I tried a new sketch too just to see if it only really affected new vs existing things, and still no luck.

Comment: Are you using a Windows text size of 100% or more? I'm still convinced that the problem is related to high DPI monitors... https://forum.solidworks.com/thread/106843

Answer (score 1):

There is no SolidWorks system option for this but there is a document option property you can use:
[image]

If you set it ON the text of the dimensions will show at the same size, even when zooming.
But since you are using a larger screen resolution, this will be too small.

If you set it OFF, you can set the scale of the dimension text to be scaled larger on a per document basis. If you want to use this setting everywhere, the only option is to change this in your template document.

It might be a good idea to file an enhancement request to SolidWorks for handling larger screen resolutions. It feels like this will be needed more and more in the future. If you put the link here, I will vote for it.

Comment: Where are the document properties?

Comment: menu tools-options (or use the icon with the gear in the titlebar)